# Leaflet 0.7: Disable mouse clicks for a polyline or a polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My leaflet (version 0.7) map includes some markers and some paths (polylines, polygons).  The users should interact with the markers by clicking on them, but not with the paths.  Currently, if a path is drawn over a marker, it can can catch the click event and prevent the marker from being clicked.

What could be done in order to prevent the paths from receiving mouse events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clickable: False` to your path's `options` to prevent mouse interactions:

```
L.polyline(latlngs, {clickable: false}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please note that the `clickable` option is only for Leaflet 0.7.x. For Leaflet 1.0.0 and later this option has been renamed into `interactive`. See the docs at  http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#interactive-layer-interactive